# Ruby On Rails: Change database username and password

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I'm not familiar with Ruby on Rails, but I have been asked to move a RoR application from one server to another. It all seems to work except I get this log entry in log/production.log:

```
Mysql2::Error (Access denied for user 'root'@'10.0.0.76' (using password: NO)):
```

However, in my database.yml file, I'm not using the root user. Here is what it looks like:

```
 development:
   adapter: mysql2
   encoding: utf8
   reconnect: false
   database: astral
   pool: 5
   username: some_user_name
   password: xyz
   host: 10.0.0.76
   socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

 # Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
 # re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
 # Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
 test:
   adapter: mysql2
   encoding: utf8
   reconnect: false
   database: astral
   pool: 5
   username: some_user_name
   password: xyz
   socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

 production:
   development
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Does the IP address in the error message change if you change it in the config file? if not I would guess that your editing the wrong config file or you need to restart the web server etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't realise this, and now I feel quite stupid. However, maybe someone who is just starting out will be able to save themselves a few minutes of head-bashing by this answer.

It turns out that changes to the database.yml file are only applied once the apache service is restarted/reloaded. Everything is working fine now.